# Why does C++ posix_memalign give the wrong array size?

Tags: c++

I have the following C++ code, which tries to read a binary file, and print out the resulting 32 bit values as hex:

```
// hello.cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
int main()
{
    int file_size;   // font file size in bytes
    int i;
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    std::string binary_data_file("font.dat");
    struct stat statbuff;
    stat(binary_data_file.c_str(), &statbuff);
    file_size = statbuff.st_size;

    void *data_buffer;
    posix_memalign(&data_buffer, 4096, file_size);
    std::ifstream data_input_file(binary_data_file.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    data_input_file.read((char *) data_buffer, file_size);
    data_input_file.close();
    int * debug_buffer = (int * ) data_buffer;

    for (int j = 0; j< 148481; j++) {
        std::cout << "Data size: " << std::dec << file_size <<  std::endl;
        std::cout << "Element: " << j << " Value: " << std::hex << *(debug_buffer + j) << std::endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

This code causes a Segmentation Fault when j == 148480

```
Data size: 211200
Element: 148477 Value: 0
Data size: 211200
Element: 148478 Value: 0
Data size: 211200
Element: 148479 Value: 0
Data size: 211200
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Why is this the case? Surely the buffer size should be equal to 211200, right, so j should be able to go up to 211200?

Comment: The size passed to `posix_memalign` is a number of bytes. Your `j` is a number of `int` elements. `int` elements are likely four bytes each in your C++ implementation. Then there are only 211,200/4 = 52,800 `int` elements available in 211,200 bytes. In future debugging questions, always include a [mre].

Comment: @EricPostpischil This was as small as I could get I thought. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas: This is too minimal, as it doesn't include enough to compile.

Comment: Editted question to compile using g++ hello.cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You allocated `211200` bytes, but you're trying to access `148481 * sizeof(int)` bytes, which is far past the end of the buffer (and past the end of the file content).

Comment: Secondary question: Why don't I get a segmentation fault when trying to access (211200/sizeof(int) +1) ? (Why only at 148480)

Comment: @Jonas: Because your C/C++ runtime library's heap allocator is splitting up really-large blocks gotten from the OS, so neighboring addresses are often valid (but belonging to some other object).  You might be interested in the alternative allocator "electric fence" `efence` that obtains every allocation directly from the OS, with intentional gaps in between marked as "access forbidden".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_Fence